# Improve performance of generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes?

Tags: ios, swift

I am successfully extracting images from a video using this closure (where `imageHashRate` is an array of type `NSValue`). I am extracting 90 images from three seconds of video at equal intervals:

```
imageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes(imageHashRate) {(requestedTime, image, actualTime, result, error) -> Void in
            if (result == .Succeeded) {
                imageArray.append(UIImage(CGImage: image!, scale:1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right))
                NSLog("SUCCESS!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine except processing of the images is slow (~6.6 seconds for 90 images). I started looking at the timing between "SUCCESS!" messages and here's what I found:

The amount of time it takes to process the first image is ~0.027 seconds. The amount of time it takes to process the second image is ~0.030 seconds. Third image, ~0.032 seconds. The 10th, 20th and 30th image take ~0.053, ~0.082 and ~0.14 seconds to process, respectively. Quite a significant slowdown.

After the 30th image, something interesting happens. Processing time dramatically decreases with the 31st image being processed in ~0.017 seconds. Then processing times increase incrementally until they reach a peak again with the 60th image. Like before, the image processing time for the 61st image drops dramatically.

Here is a graph I made showing the processing time's cyclical tendencies:

[image: processing time per image]

Here is a graph showing that shows the change in processing time from the previous image. I think it gives a good view of the process being relatively stable for the first 10 images or so then becoming very unstable:

[image: change in processing time from previous image]

Here's what I have tried so far to improve processing time:

1. Run the closure through GCD (no effect on performance)
2. Split my `imageHashRate` array into multiple arrays of about 8-10 values because the image generator runs satisfactorily for the first 10 images. Run all those arrays through a GCD group (no effect on performance)
3. Use `autoreleasepool{}` on the line that appends the image to the `imageArray`. (no effect on performance)

Any ideas on what is causing this slowdown and how to improve the performance?

Comment: Can you use the Time Profiler and find the code that is executing slowly on every 10th (/or 11th?) image?

Comment: @RoboticCat I'm sorry the graphs aren't labeled well on the x-axis. To clarify, the code is executing incrementally more slowly leading up to the 30th/31st image. Then there is some of easing of "pressure" and the process repeats itself. I ran the time profiler and it looks like there is some slowdown related to the closure. Here is a screenshot of my time profiler output: http://i.imgur.com/ko2h3db.png

Comment: What's the source movie (especially its format), and is the performance different on movies of a different format? Does the processing time depend on the timestamp of the first frame you're asking for? If your source movie contains evenly spaced keyframes (for instance, one per second), I imagine that it will be quicker to generate images for timestamps directly after the keyframes. There may not be much you can do about that.

Comment: @KurtRevis The movie file is a .mov file that I am recording from an AVCaptureSession in the app. The .mov file is saved to the NSTemporaryDirectory. I am currently recording at the High quality preset on an iPhone6s. I can downgrade the quality of the video, and indeed the processing goes very quickly with the AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720 session preset, but with every format of higher resolution, the lag in processing is witnessed.

Comment: Hey @BryanR . Would LOVE to hear if you found something about this. Thanks!

Comment: @RoiMulia I have talked with a few friends about this and they all agree that this is a highly academic problem which likely requires understanding of the architecture of the the iPhone hardware itself. So unfortunately, I do not expect a watershed moment.

Comment: @BryanR Thanks for replying.. Sometimes it's just not up to us the developers lol

Comment: Have you tried using contiguous frame timestamps? I'm thinking it's possible that the decoder optimizations the dev docs mention are only applicable when the ["series of images"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator) are requested as contiguous frame timestamps, even though it should certainly be theoretically possible to decode + ignore/drop non-requested intermediary frames.

Comment: @DustinKerstein I have not looked at this code for a few years, and it is entirely possible that newer iPhones would not have the same issues my iPhone 5 had given the improvements in processing power. But this certainly could be a solution.